# What is the proper usage of CollectionViewSource in terms of MVVM in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, collectionviewsource

`CollectionViewSource` class is supposed to provide a so-called "view" over data. This includes data filtering, sorting and grouping.

Now, one may think, that this is a responsibility of a View in MVVM architecture, but very often it is user, who decides, what kind of grouping, sorting or filtering he wants. These are business decisions, which belongs to viewmodel. Moreover, filtering is performed by taking an element and deciding, whether it matches filter or not, and that is definitely viewmodel's responsibility (possibly then passed to a service).

It seems then, that `CollectionViewSource` is a good candidate to be directly exposed from the viewmodel, because the latter then have full control over its properties (eg. `GroupDescriptions`). But even though this class resides in Windows.Data namespace, it is still in PresentationFramework assembly and I feel really uncomfortable to reference it from my BusinessLogic assembly, because I'm hardly tying it to a specific (*nomen omen*) presentation framework.

From what I saw, the most common place for CollectionViewSource are control's (window's) resources from which (surprisingly) I can bind to the viewmodel. But then manipulating filtering, sorting and grouping is a mess, because you have to push information manually between view and viewmodel. Just for one example:

```xml
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SuggestionItems" Source="{Binding Suggestions}">
  <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="{Binding SuggestionGroupByProperty}"/>
  </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

This will not work, because `PropertyGroupDescription.PropertyName` is not a `DependencyProperty`. So I'd probably have to design my own Xaml extension to be able to bind such information from viewmodel to a view.

I failed to find any tutorial or documentation on how is `ColletionViewSource` supposed to fit into MVVM/WPF framework. I actually got an impression, that this is not really too much thought-through, because, for instance, placing the `CollectionViewSource` anywhere outside resources requires some really nasty shenanigans to simply push collection inside.

For example (mind the `SelectedItem`):

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <DataGrid.DataContext>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="myViewSource" Source="{Binding MyCollection}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_OnFilter">
      <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Container" />
      </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </DataGrid.DataContext>
  <!-- (...) -->
</DataGrid>
```

So how the `CollectionViewSource` should canonically fit into the MVVM pattern, so that viewmodel has enough control over it? And if it shouldn't, then how this scenario (collection grouping, sorting, filtering) should actually look in MVVM?

Comment: Collection views are usually business of the view. When the data itself must be filtered ot sorted then the view model will sort the collection directly. If the data should be only filtered for user presentation for example columns in a data table or items of a tree view, then the view e.g. the responsible control will take care of creating and managing required views. That's why a view model usually has no interest in any collection view. Generally, collection views are the extra layer introduced for the UI to allow e.g. filtering in the UI without manipulating the original data source.

Comment: @BionicCode The sorting and filtering fits your comment, but you omit the grouping and actually this poses a problem for me. For instance, the way entries are grouped is defined in application configuration so IMO this should go through the viewmodel. Or am I wrong? Should view be allowed to interpret the application configuration?

Comment: No, my comment also applies for grouping. If grouping data is a application low level business concern, it is done by the model. If grouping is only of interest for the user like customizing the view it is responsibility of the view to do this.

Comment: For example you can sort, filter or group the files of the filesystem e.g. in Windows Explorer. The data itself is a simple tree structure. It is not sorted or grouped by the OS on low level. Only the presentation is sorted or grouped. You can open two Explorer Window instances to view the same folder. You can sort one window by date and the other by name. This is possible because of virtual data structure manipulation on view level. Your view model should not be concerned with any view related logic or presentation details.

Comment: As i said before, when grouping or sorting is a business concern, then you have different possibilities to sort or group data. You don't want to modify a virtual view representation in this case, but the original collection. You either group using LINQ or by introducing data models to create a collection of groups. If grouping is a concern of the view only, the you can define a CollectionViewSource either in XAML or using a IValueConverter to return a ICollectionView (e.g., by handling a CollectionViewSource). Another solution is to encapsulate this logic in a control.

Comment: For example you can extend ListView to provide a more complex or dynamic grouping logic. Take the DataGrid as an example. It allows sorting by clicking the column's header. This logic is all implemented in the control rather than in the client code (e.g. view model). The DataGrid manipulates the data presentation without modifying the original collection, in order to allow different presentation of the same data by different data views.

Comment: If you don't want to allow individual data presentation, then the sorting or grouping becomes a concern of the view model, which would then operate on the original collection instead of the collection's view. I hope that I could make it clear that it depends on your use case whether your view does the operations on a virtual collection view or the view model performs the operations on the original collection or the model already provides the data sorted or grouped (if this is a business concern).

Comment: Doing it this way, also allows you to avoid introducing a dependency of your view model to any WPF specific assembly. I also have to note, that having a dependency to a certain assembly does not violate the MVVM pattern. The pattern is more concerned with structuring responsibilities in components (view view model and model). But as you already have correctly observed, the PresentationFramework assembly only contains view related types like Binding or IValueConverter or namespaces like System.Windows.Controls.

Answer (score 0):

I use CollectionViewSource like this

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSourceResource}}" />
```